# conditional operator giving result as 28 on every input?

Tags: c

short program to find the number of days in the month of February depending on whether it is a leap year or not without using control structure branching statements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char a;
  int b;
  printf("Press 1 for leap year else Press any character:");
  scanf("%c",&a);
  (a==1)?(b=29):(b=28); 
  printf("Number of days in February=%d",b);
  return 0;
}
```

it gives same result 28 as answer?

Comment: Why don't you do e.g. `b = (a == 1 ? 29 : 28)`? Also try to avoid the ternary (conditional) expression as much as you can, as it tends to make code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: As for your problem, what do you really ask `scanf` to read? Is it an *`int`*? I know of no encoding where `1 == '1'`.

Comment: As Joachim hinted, you need `b = (a == '1' ? 29 : 28)` or `b = (a == 1+'0' ? 29 : 28)`

Answer (score 1):

This is because a is not equal to 1 but to the character '1' so you have to write : 
`(a == '1')?(b=29):(b=28);`

Answer (score 1):

Change data type of variable a to integer. Try this it will work fine.

```
 int main()
 {
  int a,b;
  printf("Press 1 for leap year else Press any character:");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  (a==1)?(b=29):(b=28); 
  printf("Number of days in February=%d",b);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the input as 1.
Your code is comparing a character '1' with an integer 1.ascii value of '1' is 49.
So, 49!=1
Hence, your code executes the false block.

So,you have to replace the condition with`(a=='1')?(b=29):(b=28);`.